# get_meta_tags() connection refused

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, proxy

In my php code i am using `get_meta_tags()` to fetch meta information from the site. But my proxy server is refusing connections and i am getting the following error:

**Warning: get_meta_tags(http://www.espncricinfo.com/) [function.get-meta-tags]: failed to open stream: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**

Can anyone tell me how to by pass the proxy in my php code?

I tried setting proxy in Eclipse XDebug configuration but i don't think that is the right way to do it.

In `curl` i specified the proxy as `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "host:port");` which worked fine but in php i don't know the procedure. 
Any help would be appreciated.

-Adithya

Answer (score 2):

By default PHP doesn't use a proxy. To bypass via a proxy, you can add a proxy for all functions using the [http stream wrapper <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) (that wrapper is taking care for "filenames" starting with `http://` or `https://`) like in your [`get_meta_tags`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/get_meta_tags) function example.

There are many [HTTP context options <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php), the one you're looking for is `proxy`.

As `get_meta_tags` does not accept a context parameter (only a filename parameter), you need to change the so called *default context* which is (normally) used by PHP functions accepting a filename parameter. It's set with [`stream_context_get_default`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/stream_context_get_default).

```
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'proxy' => 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8000'
    )
);
stream_context_get_default($opts);
```

Unfortunately `get_meta_tags` looks like an exception to the general rule to use stream wrappers at all (at least with my PHP 5.3.8 version). But no worries, you can slip the data you would like to obtain the meta tags from into `get_meta_tags` with using the default context.

This can be done with the [`data://` stream wrapper<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php). A little helper function takes care for the conversion:

```
/**
 * obtain $filename content as data:// URI
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php
 *
 * @param string $filename
 * @return string data:// URI
 */
function filename_data_uri($filename)
{
    $buffer = file_get_contents($filename);

    $mime = 'text/plain';
    # obtain mime type and charset from http response (if available)
    if (isset($http_response_header))
        foreach($http_response_header as $header)
            sscanf($header, 'Content-Type: %[^]]', $mime)
    ;

    return "data://$mime;base64,".base64_encode($buffer);       
};
```

This function allows to obtain contents from an URL with `file_get_contents` which makes use of the default stream context. That is the one the proxy was configured for.

You then can combine this with `get_meta_tags`:

```
$url = 'http://www.espncricinfo.com/';
$url = filename_data_uri($url);
$meta_tags = get_meta_tags($url);
```

`get_meta_tags` now operates on the contents of `$url` which has been already fetched with the `filename_data_uri` function while using the proxy. The full example:

```
$url = 'http://www.espncricinfo.com/';
$proxy = 'tcp://host:port';

// configure default context to use proxy
$opts['http']['proxy'] = $proxy;
$resource = stream_context_get_default($opts);

// obtain url contents with default context
$data = filename_data_uri($url);
$meta_tags = get_meta_tags($data);
print_r($meta_tags);

/**
 * obtain $filename content as data:// URI
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php
 *
 * @param string $filename
 * @return string data:// URI
 */
function filename_data_uri($filename)
{
    $buffer = file_get_contents($filename);

    $mime = 'text/plain';
    # obtain mime type and charset from http response (if available)
    if (isset($http_response_header))
        foreach($http_response_header as $header)
            sscanf($header, 'Content-Type: %[^]]', $mime)
    ;

    return "data://$mime;base64,".base64_encode($buffer);       
};
```

Comment: I tried your code but that doesn't help either ! I am getting the following error :

Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.espncricinfo.com/) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 502 Proxy Error ( The Uniform Resource Locator (URL) does not use a recognized protocol.

I am able to fetch the website content using curl (by configuring proxy) which i tried passing it to the get_meta_tags function but that didn't work. I read that get_meta_tags also takes in a string but that didn't work.

$buffer is always being false.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the protocol in the http header ?